# Проблема запустить приложение SpringBoot

Tags: java, java-8

На сколько я понимаю, не могу создать зависимости для подключения базы (H2)..В чем может быть проблема?

```
package tacos.data;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import tacos.Ingredient;

@Repository
public class JdbcIngredientRepository implements IngredientRepository {

    private  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public JdbcIngredientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Ingredient> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "select id, name, type from Ingredient",
                this::mapRowToIngredient);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Ingredient> findById(String id) {
        List<Ingredient> results = jdbcTemplate.query(
                "select id, name, type from Ingredient where id=?",
                this::mapRowToIngredient,
                id);
        return results.size() == 0 ?
                Optional.empty() :
                Optional.of(results.get(0));
    }

    @Override
    public Ingredient save(Ingredient ingredient) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values (?, ?, ?)",
                ingredient.getId(),
                ingredient.getName(),
                ingredient.getType().toString());
        return ingredient;
    }

    private Ingredient mapRowToIngredient(ResultSet row, int rowNum)
            throws SQLException {
        return new Ingredient(
                row.getString("id"),
                row.getString("name"),
                Ingredient.Type.valueOf(row.getString("type")));
    }

  /*
  @Override
  public Ingredient findById(String id) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "select id, name, type from Ingredient where id=?",
        new RowMapper<Ingredient>() {
          public Ingredient mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
              throws SQLException {
            return new Ingredient(
                rs.getString("id"),
                rs.getString("name"),
                Ingredient.Type.valueOf(rs.getString("type")));
          };
        }, id);
  }
   */

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже вы ошиблись в описании схемы. Видимо `Ingredient_Ref.Ingredient` пытается быть внешним ключём для несуществующего первичного в таблице `Ingredient`. Проверьте, может быть вы используете не `Id` в качестве имени стоблца с первычиным ключом в таблице `Ingredient`?

Comment: alter table Taco
    add foreign key (taco_order) references Taco_Order(id);
alter table Ingredient_Ref
    add foreign key (ingredient) references Ingredient(id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это пример из книги "Spring in action, sixth edition"(может есть и в более ранних).

В код создания таблиц необходимо внести следующие изменения:

```
id identity -> id identity not null

ingredient varchar(4) not null -> ingredient varchar(4) primary key not null

id varchar(4) not null -> id varchar(4) primary key not null
```

После этого все должно собраться.